# IEnumerable<T>.Single and casting

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I a have 2 objects A and B. B is inherited from A and has some more properties.
I have IEnumerable{A} that contains only B objects.
What I want to do is:

```
list.Single(b => b.PropertyThatOnlyExistOnB == "something")
```

I would have expect something like this to work:

```
list.Single((B) b => b.PropertyThatOnlyExistOnB == "something")
```

But it doesn't compile. For now I just doing:

```
B result = null;
foreach (b in list)
{
     if((B)b.PropertyThatOnlyExistOnB == "something")
     {
      result = (B)b;
     }
}
```

Is there a shorter way?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`Enumerable.OfType<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) extension methods to filter/cast.

```
list.OfType<B>().Single(b => b.PropertyThatOnlyExistOnB == "something")
```

Answer (score 4):

Although I like @VirtualBlackFox's answer best, for completeness sake: Here is how to get your idea to work:

```
list.Single(b => ((B)b).PropertyThatOnlyExistOnB == "something");
```

You weren't that far off track, except that you got some of the syntax confused. The `b => EXPRESSION` syntax denotes a lambda expression. You can't start altering the stuff before the `=>`, unless you want to add (or remove) arguments:

```
* `x => LAMBDA_WITH_ONE_PARAMETER`
* `(x) => LAMBDA_WITH_ONE_PARAMETER`
* `() => LAMBDA_WITH_NO_PARAMETERS`
* `(x, y, z) => LAMBDA_WITH_THREE_PARAMETERS`
```

Comment: You risk InvalidCastExceptions being thrown. How are you ensuring that only instances of B are in the enumeration?

Comment: I'm not. OP says he is sure, only instances of `B` are in the enumeration. Sometimes you just are sure ;) Also, `Single()` will raise an exception, if there are no `B` instances in the enumeration as well. Just saying.

Comment: @Matthew Abbot: also, I just wanted to show OP how to get his code right. I remember stating that I prefer (and, btw, +1)  VirtualBlackFox's answer!

Comment: Lol, I wasn't poking holes, it is a perfectly valid answer, but should *his* definition change, this will break.

Answer (score 2):

> I have `IEnumerable<A>` that contains only B objects.

I would question this statement about your variable. You've specified that it is an `IEnumerable<A>`, but it contains only instances of `B`. What is the purpose of this? If you are explicitly only requiring instances of `B` in all circumstances, it would be better for this to be an `IEnumerable<B>`, as it safeguards problems that could be caught at compile time.

Consider the following, I would imagine that you may have some code similar to:

```
var setOfA = // Get a set of A.
DoSomethingWithA(setOfA);

var instanceOfB = GetInstanceOfB(setOfA);
```

In this case, I can understand that an `IEnumerable<A>` is perfectly valid, except when you want to perform the latter operation, `GetInstanceOfB`. Let's imagine, the definition is:

```
B GetInstanceOfB(IEnumerable<A> setOfA)
{
    return // The answer to your question.
}
```

Now, the initial problem I hope you see, is that you're putting all your cards on the notion that your list (`setOfA` in my example), is always only going to contain instances of `B`. While you may guarantee that from your developer point of view, the compiler can make no such assumption, it can only guarantee that `setOfA` (list) is an `IEnumerable<A>`, and therein lies the potential issue.

Looking at the answers provided (all of which are perfectly valid [@VirtualBlackFox being the safest answer] given your notion):

> I have `IEnumerable<A>` that contains only B objects.

What if, in some future change, `setOfA`, also contains an instance of `C` (a potential future subclass of `A`). Given this answer:

```
list.Single(b => ((B)b).PropertyThatOnlyExistOnB == "something");
```

What if `setOfA` is actually: `[C B B]`. You can see that the explicit cast `(B)b` will cause an `InvalidCastException` to be thrown. Because of the nature of the `Single` operation, it will continue to enumerate until the first instance that something fails the predicate (`PropertyThatOnlyExistOnB == "something"`), or an exception is thrown. In this instance, the exception could be thrown which is unexpected, and likely unhandled. This answer, is similar to:

```
list.Cast<B>().Single(b => b.PropertyThatOnlyExistOnB == "something");
```

Given this answer:

```
list.Single<A>(b => (b as B).PropertyThatOnlyExistOnB == "something")
```

In the same situation, the exception would arise as a thrown instance of `NullReferenceException`, because the instance of `C` cannot be safely type cast to `B`.

Now, don't get me wrong, I am *not* picking holes with those answers, as I said they are perfectly valid given the remit of your question. But in circumstances where your code changes, those perfectly valid answers become potential future issues.

Given this answer:

```
list.OfType<B>.Single(b => b.PropertyThatOnlyExistOnB == "something");
```

This allows you to safely type cast to a potential subset of `A` that are in fact `B`, and the compiler can guarantee that your predicate is only being used on an `IEnumerable<B>`.

But this would lead me to discovering that the juncture in your code is trying to handle your `IEnumerable<A>` but perform an operation where you really want your `IEnumerable<B>`. In which case, shouldn't you refactor this code to possibly have an explicit method:

```
B GetMatchingInstanceOfB(IEnumerable<B> setOfB)
{
    if (setOfB == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("setOfB");

    return setOfB.Single(b => b.PropertyThatOnlyExistOnB == "something");
}
```

The change in the design of the method ensures that it will only explicitly accept a valid set of `B`, and you don't have to worry about your cast within that method. The method is responsible only for matching a single item of `B`.

This of course means you need to push your cast out to a different level, but that still is much more explicit:

```
var b = GetMatchingInstanceOfB(setOfA.OfType<B>());
```

I'm also assuming that you have sufficient error handling in place in circumstances where the predicate will fail where all instances are `B`, e.g., more than 1 item satisfies `PropertyThatOnlyExistOnB == "something"`.

This might have been a pointless rant about reviewing your code, but I think it is worth considering unexpected situations that could arise, and how potentially tweaking your variables can save you a potential headache in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine:

```
list.Single<A>(b => (b as B).PropertyThatOnlyExistOnB == "something")
```

If you dont want to risk exceptions to be thrown you can do this:

```
list.Single<A>(b => ((b is B)&&((b as B).PropertyThatOnlyExistOnB == "something")))
```

Comment: Won't you risk a possibly NullReferenceException where the item is not an instance of B?

Comment: Its either NullReferenceException or InvallidCastException (when you ((B)b).Property . Your pick ;)

Comment: + rep for clear attitude :) I agree that there is no reason to use IEnumerable<A> when you are sure it contains only objects of type B. Ive edited my answer to remove the risk of Exception.